# oracle update trigger using case/if

Tags: oracle, triggers

I want to update a table with sort of a status. the status should be displayed using three traffic-light-pictures. I successfully made a view which fills the corresponding traffic-light-picture (filepath) depending on the other attributes. (*ampel_rot.jpg* is a red traffic-light, *ampel_gelb.jpg* is a yellow traffic-light, *ampel_gruen.jpg is a green traffic-light)

```
case when (L.STATUS = 'Aktiv' AND (((select count(*) from INFOVERSAND_FILES I where I.FID_BAUGESUCH=L.FID) = 0) AND ((select count(*) from ENTWAESSERUNGSPLAN_FILES E where E.FID_BAUGESUCH=L.FID)= 0)  AND ((select count(*) from DOKKTV_FILES K where K.FID_BAUGESUCH=L.FID) = 0) AND L.ABWASSER_EINMASS is NULL AND  L.ABWASSER_ABNAHME is NULL AND  L.PAW is NULL AND  L.DOK_K_TV is NULL AND  L.DICHTHEITSPRUEFUNG is NULL AND  L.SANIERUNGSVERFUEGUNG is NULL AND  L.NACHPRUEFUNG is NULL AND  L.ABSCHLUSS is NULL AND  L.KOMMENTAR is NULL)) then 'C:\Temp\Ampel_rot.jpg' 
when (L.STATUS = 'Aktiv' AND (((select count(*) from INFOVERSAND_FILES I where I.FID_BAUGESUCH=L.FID) > 0) OR ((select count(*) from ENTWAESSERUNGSPLAN_FILES E where E.FID_BAUGESUCH=L.FID)> 0)  OR ((select count(*) from DOKKTV_FILES K where K.FID_BAUGESUCH=L.FID) > 0) OR L.ABWASSER_EINMASS is not NULL OR L.ABWASSER_ABNAHME is not NULL OR L.PAW is not NULL OR L.DOK_K_TV is not NULL OR L.DICHTHEITSPRUEFUNG is not NULL OR L.SANIERUNGSVERFUEGUNG is not NULL OR L.NACHPRUEFUNG is not NULL OR L.ABSCHLUSS is not NULL OR L.KOMMENTAR is not NULL) AND L.ABSCHLUSS is NULL AND L.ABSCHLUSS_ZUSATZ is NULL) then 'C:\Temp\Ampel_gelb.jpg'
when (L.ABSCHLUSS is not NULL OR L.ABSCHLUSS_ZUSATZ is not NULL) then 'C:\Temp\Ampel_gruen.jpg' end as Ampel
from LIEGENSCHAFT L
```

Unfortunately I need these traffic-light-filepaths in the table directly, as 
views are read-only.
So I tried to write another update-trigger, with no success so far:

I tried with IF:

```
create or replace
  TRIGGER LS_STATUS
  before UPDATE ON LIEGENSCHAFT  
  for each row
  DECLARE
  AMP VARCHAR2(50) := 'C:\Temp\Ampel_rot'
  BEGIN
  if :new.STATUS = 'Aktiv' AND (:new.ABWASSER_EINMASS is NULL AND :new.ABWASSER_ABNAHME is NULL AND :new.PAW is NULL AND :new.DOK_K_TV is NULL AND :new.DICHTHEITSPRUEFUNG is NULL AND :new.SANIERUNGSVERFUEGUNG is NULL AND :new.NACHPRUEFUNG is NULL AND :new.ABSCHLUSS is NULL AND :new.KOMMENTAR is NULL)) then AMP:='C:\Temp\Ampel_rot.jpg' else 'leer' END IF;   
  :NEW.AMPEL := AMP;
  END;
```

and also using case:

```
create or replace
  TRIGGER LS_STATUS
  before UPDATE ON LIEGENSCHAFT  
  for each row
  DECLARE
  AMP VARCHAR2(50) := 'C:\Temp\Ampel_rot'
  BEGIN
  AMP := select case when :new.STATUS = 'Aktiv' AND (:new.ABWASSER_EINMASS is NULL AND  :new.ABWASSER_ABNAHME is NULL AND :new.PAW is NULL AND  :new.DOK_K_TV is NULL AND  :new.DICHTHEITSPRUEFUNG is NULL AND  :new.SANIERUNGSVERFUEGUNG is NULL AND  :new.NACHPRUEFUNG is NULL AND  :new.ABSCHLUSS is NULL AND  :new.KOMMENTAR is NULL)) then 'C:\Temp\Ampel_rot.jpg' else 'leer' END;
:NEW.AMPEL := AMP;
END;
```

I only tried to do the red traffic-light to begin. When this works, I can add the other definitions...

Comment: "with no success so far" What does that mean? You got an error? You got unexpected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, you have several syntax errors. If you format your code, they'd be more obvious. You also might try using an IDE with syntax highlighting, like SQL Developer or TOAD, which will point out these kind of problems.

See my comments below. In the first one:

```
create or replace
  TRIGGER LS_STATUS
  before UPDATE ON LIEGENSCHAFT  
  for each row
  DECLARE
    AMP VARCHAR2(50) := 'C:\Temp\Ampel_rot' -- missing ; at end
  BEGIN
  if :new.STATUS = 'Aktiv' AND 
    (:new.ABWASSER_EINMASS is NULL 
     AND :new.ABWASSER_ABNAHME is NULL 
     AND :new.PAW is NULL 
     AND :new.DOK_K_TV is NULL 
     AND :new.DICHTHEITSPRUEFUNG is NULL 
     AND :new.SANIERUNGSVERFUEGUNG is NULL 
     AND :new.NACHPRUEFUNG is NULL 
     AND :new.ABSCHLUSS is NULL 
     AND :new.KOMMENTAR is NULL)
     ) -- what's this? no matching left parenthesis.
  then 
     AMP:='C:\Temp\Ampel_rot.jpg' -- missing ;
  else 
     'leer' -- also what's this? It should be "AMP:='leer';"
  END IF;   
  :NEW.AMPEL := AMP;
END;
```

And in the second one:

```
create or replace
  TRIGGER LS_STATUS
  before UPDATE ON LIEGENSCHAFT  
  for each row
  DECLARE
    AMP VARCHAR2(50) := 'C:\Temp\Ampel_rot' -- missing ; at end
  BEGIN
  AMP := select -- if you want a select, put 'from dual' at the end. but a select isn't needed here.
    case 
    when :new.STATUS = 'Aktiv' 
        AND (:new.ABWASSER_EINMASS is NULL 
            AND  :new.ABWASSER_ABNAHME is NULL 
            AND :new.PAW is NULL 
            AND  :new.DOK_K_TV is NULL 
            AND  :new.DICHTHEITSPRUEFUNG is NULL 
            AND  :new.SANIERUNGSVERFUEGUNG is NULL 
            AND  :new.NACHPRUEFUNG is NULL 
            AND  :new.ABSCHLUSS is NULL 
            AND  :new.KOMMENTAR is NULL)
        ) -- also no matching left paren
    then 'C:\Temp\Ampel_rot.jpg' 
    else 'leer' 
    END;
:NEW.AMPEL := AMP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for pointing out my syntax errors as well as pointing me to SQL-Developer, that's a whole new world!
I corrected the code and it's working now.
Now on to my last problem/question:
I want to check 3 dependent tables for associated objects. In my view I could just put three select counts in and filter if they are zero. Is there any possibilty to use it this way in a trigger?
here's my attempt which gives compiling errors in SQL Developer:

```
create or replace
  TRIGGER LS_STATUS
  before UPDATE ON LIEGENSCHAFT  
  for each row
  DECLARE
    AMP VARCHAR2(50) := 'C:\Temp\Ampel_rot';
  BEGIN
  if :new.STATUS = 'Aktiv' AND 
    (:new.ABWASSER_EINMASS is NULL 
     AND :new.ABWASSER_ABNAHME is NULL 
     AND :new.PAW is NULL 
     AND :new.DOK_K_TV is NULL 
     AND :new.DICHTHEITSPRUEFUNG is NULL 
     AND :new.SANIERUNGSVERFUEGUNG is NULL 
     AND :new.NACHPRUEFUNG is NULL 
     AND :new.ABSCHLUSS is NULL 
     AND :new.KOMMENTAR is NULL
     AND ((select count(*) from INFOVERSAND_FILES I where I.FID_BAUGESUCH=FID) = 0)
     AND ((select count(*) from ENTWAESSERUNGSPLAN_FILES E where E.FID_BAUGESUCH=FID) = 0)
     AND ((select count(*) from DOKKTV_FILES K where K.FID_BAUGESUCH=FID) = 0))
  then 
     AMP:='C:\Temp\Ampel_rot.jpg';
  else
  AMP:='leer'; 
  END IF;   
  :NEW.AMPEL := AMP;
END;
```

In the end it was working this way:

```
create or replace
  TRIGGER LS_STATUS
  before UPDATE ON LIEGENSCHAFT  
  for each row
  DECLARE
    AMP VARCHAR2(50) := 'C:\Temp\Ampel_rot';
    CSchriftverkehr NUMBER(1);
    CEntwaesserungsplan NUMBER(1);
    CDOKKTV NUMBER(1);
  BEGIN
  select count(*) into CSchriftverkehr from INFOVERSAND_FILES I where I.FID_BAUGESUCH=:new.FID;
  select count(*) into CEntwaesserungsplan from ENTWAESSERUNGSPLAN_FILES E where E.FID_BAUGESUCH=:new.FID;
  select count(*) into CDOKKTV from DOKKTV_FILES K where K.FID_BAUGESUCH=:new.FID;
  if :new.STATUS = 'Aktiv' AND 
    (:new.ABWASSER_EINMASS is NULL 
     AND :new.ABWASSER_ABNAHME is NULL 
     AND :new.PAW is NULL 
     AND :new.DOK_K_TV is NULL 
     AND :new.DICHTHEITSPRUEFUNG is NULL 
     AND :new.SANIERUNGSVERFUEGUNG is NULL 
     AND :new.NACHPRUEFUNG is NULL 
     AND :new.ABSCHLUSS is NULL 
     AND :new.KOMMENTAR is NULL
     AND CSchriftverkehr = 0 AND CEntwaesserungsplan = 0 AND CDOKKTV = 0)
  then 
     AMP:='C:\Temp\Ampel_rot.jpg'; -- missing ;
  else
  AMP:='leer'; 
  END IF;   
  :NEW.AMPEL := AMP;
END;
```

Comment: Nevermind, I got it working having the three selects outside the if-clause writing the results in variables.
Thx again for your small but very helpful hints!